# How to give tooltip for icon and merge two columns in tabulator

Tags: angular, tabulator

[image]I am using tabulator for tree view structure in angular 6. I want to group two columns into one and assign tooltip for the icons available in the column

Following is the screen i have designed for reference

```
sampleColumn= [
    { formatter: this.historyIcon, width: 40, align: "center", cellClick: this.showHistory.bind(this), headerSort: false },
    { formatter: this.mapIcon, width: 40, align: "center", cellClick: this.showMap.bind(this), headerSort: false },
    { field: 'locName', title: 'Location', headerSort: false }
  ];

mapIcon = function (cell, formatterParams) { //plain text value
    return "<i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i>";
  };

historyIcon = function (cell, formatterParams) { //plain text value
    return "<i class='fa fa-tasks'></i>";
  };

var sampleTable = new Tabulator("#child-item-tabulator", {
      layout: "fitColumns",
      columns: this.sampleColumn,
      placeholder: "Fetching data",
      virtualDomBuffer: 400,
      dataTree: true
    });
```

How to group formatter column and assign tooltip for icons

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tooltip with regular title attribute.

```
historyIcon = function (cell, formatterParams) { //plain text value
   return "<i class='fa fa-map-marker' title='My tooltip text'></i>";  
};
```

Comment: Yes I have done it. But i want to merge two columns into one and show these two icons near by

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do what you are doing, but if you really want to merge two columns you can set new columns in Tabulator check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/wLxefn9b/11/

```
  table.setColumns(mergedColumn);
```